# Using python, how to use collect tweets (using tweepy) between two dates?

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy, tweets

How can i use python and tweepy in order to collect tweets from twitter that are between two given dates?

is there a way to pass from...until... values to the search api?

Note:
I need to be able to search back but WITHOUT limitation to a specific user

i am using python and I know that the code should be something like this but i need help to make it work.

```
    auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(access_token_key, access_token_secret)
    api = tweepy.API(auth)

    collection = []
    for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search, ???????).items():
        collection[tweet.id] = tweet._json
```

Comment: I have to add that in the search i also don't want to limit to a specific word or hashtag
I need to do an open search.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After long hours of investigations and stabilization i can gladly share my findings.

- search by geocode: pass the geocode parameter in the 'q' parameter in this format: *geocode:"37.781157,-122.398720,500mi"* ,  **the double quotes are important**. notice that the parameter *near* is not supported anymore by this api. The geocode gives more flexibility
- search by timeline: use the parameters "since" and "until" in the following format: "since:2016-08-01 until:2016-08-02"

there is one more important note... twitter don't allow queries with too old dates. I am not sure but i think they give only 10-14 days back. So you cannot query this way for tweets of last month.

===================================

```
for status in tweepy.Cursor(api.search,
                       q='geocode:"37.781157,-122.398720,1mi" since:2016-08-01 until:2016-08-02 include:retweets',
                       result_type='recent',
                       include_entities=True,
                       monitor_rate_limit=False, 
                       wait_on_rate_limit=False).items(300):
    tweet_id = status.id
    tweet_json = status._json
```

Comment: We can go back on Twitter for a limited time. on free accounts, it's 7 days. and premium accounts for 30 days.

Answer (score 0):

As of now, Tweepy is not the best solution. The best solution is using the python library SnScrape, which scrapes twitter, and can therefore get tweets after the 2-week cap twitter sets. The below code only scrapes for 100 English tweets between dates and only gets the tweet ID, but it can be easily extended for more specific searches, more or fewer tweets, or to get more information about the tweet.

```css
import snscrape.modules.twitter as sntwitter

tweetslist = []

params="'"+"lang:en "+"since:2020-11-1"+" until:2021-03-13"+"'" 

for i,tweet in enumerate(sntwitter.TwitterSearchScraper(params).get_items()):
    if i>100:
        break
    tweetslist.append([tweet.id])

print(tweetslist)
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to use max_id parameters as described in [twitter documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/timelines)

tweepy is a wrapper around twitter API so you should be able to use this parameter.

As per geolocation, take look at [The Search API: Tweets by Place](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/search-by-place). It uses same search API, with customized keys.

Comment: thanks. i will review
in fact i am familiar with these and even wrote a code based on their instructions but i have some issue to run it and get the correct answers