# Retrieving the tweets related to a specific search between two dates

Tags: python, twitter

Im struggling to retrieve the tweets associated with a particular search between two dates. I looked at the [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39136226/using-python-how-to-use-collect-tweets-using-tweepy-between-two-dates) and used that as below, but, as the answer mentions, the code only works for tweets which are 10-14 days old and as I need tweets from 2014, it results in `tweets` being an empty list.

```
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

api = tweepy.API(auth)

tweets = []
company_name = '#' + 'Apple'
date_strng = " since:2014-10-11 until:2015-10-14"
for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search,q=company_name + date_strng,count=10000,lang="en").items():
    tweets.append(tweet)
```

Also tried the following, but it didnt work (`tweets` is again an empty list). But if I remove the `until` argument, I get the tweets since the `start_date`:

```
start_date = datetime.datetime(2014,10,11)
end_date = datetime.datetime(2015,10,14)
for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search,q=company_name,count=10000,lang="en", since=start_date,until=end_date).items():
    tweets.append(tweet)
```

Was wondering if there is a solution to this.

Thanks

Comment: first check in Twiter API documentation if they serve old tweets. They many not  send so old tweets. OR maybe they have paid version with old data.

Comment: You'd need to use the premium full-archive search API in order to retrieve Tweets from that period of time, and tweepy does not support that. You could try using the [search-tweets-python package](https://github.com/twitterdev/search-tweets-python) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Reason for the empty list is due to the fact that the standard search api retrieve only last 7 days of tweets . Since you have given the start and until dates it’s filtering the tweets as per dates. Obviously list will be empty. 
Refer the below link for retrieving old tweets

https://stackoverflow.com/a/61737450/10703097

Also you are trying 1 year duration of tweet which is a huge corpus of tweets try to modify as per your needs.