# Store all tweets tweeted during certain date range (Tweepy, Python)

Tags: python, tweepy, twitterapi-python

I am trying to retrieve all of the tweets matching a query between a start date and an end date. I am using the following code to store the tweets in a csv file:

```
for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q=searchQuery, count=100, lang="en", since="2019-12-01", until="2020-04-07").items():
       print(tweet.created_at, tweet.text)
       csvWriter.writerow([tweet.created_at, tweet.text.encode('utf-8')])
       tweetCountTest += 1
       print(tweetCountTest)
```

It works fine if I set the end (until) date after 2020-05-05, but just exits the loop when I put any date before that. Is there something wrong with my code? Ideally, I want to be able to store all the tweets matching my query tweeted in any date range. Today is 2020-05-12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are so many solutions already posted in stackoverflow for the same topic, you could have done some research to get your answer before posting.

Standard search only can fetch last 7 days of tweets, that’s why when you give until to latest, you are able to fetch the tweets.

In order to fetch older tweets you need to have premium api or sandbox access detail explanation is given in this post

https://stackoverflow.com/a/61737450/10703097

Comment: Yes I probably should have looked a little further. I misread the API documentation and was very confused as to why my code wasn't working. I realized this a few hours after posting this question.